# Template with pointer to member function

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I'm trying to write a template for a function object to act as a predicate in a STL algorithm function. Im still quite new to this and i cant get it quite right

here is the template:

```
#ifndef MEMBERPREDICATE_H
#define MEMBERPREDICATE_H

template <typename Type, typename Class>
class MemberPredicate{
public:
    MemberPredicate(Type (Class::*method)(), bool (*operation)(Type,Type), Type data) : method(method), operation(operation), data(data){};
    bool operator()(Class * other){ return *(this->operation)(other->*(this->method)(), this->data);}
private:
    Type (Class::*method)();
    bool (*operation)(Type,Type);
    Type data;
};
#endif
```

The constructor takes a pointer to a (get)method of the class, a pointer to a comparison operator acting on values returned by that get method and finaly some data that it should use for comparisons

Im trying to use the template in the following way:

```
bool equal(int a, int b){
    return a == b;
}

MemberPredicate<int, IntClass> pred(&IntClass::getInt, &equal, 4)
IntClass * i = new IntClass(5) // stores 5 in IntClass and returns this value when i->getInt() is called
pred(i);
```

i can compile just fine when im not using the function part of the function object but when i try to apply it to `i` i get an error:

```
Must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer to member function in Member...
bool operator()(Class * other){ return *(this->operation)(other->*(this->method)(), this->data);}
```

And here the marker is under the arrow `other->`
I've tried chaing the arrows to points and to move them around a bit at random but cant get it to work.

As i said im wuite new to this and it might very well be that this is a very strange way to go about things. if thats the case pointers in the right direction are very welcome, but i would still like to grasp this part.

Finally i have a bonus question, I will want to make the get-method const after i get this part working, but im not sure how, any help here would also be nice.

Thank you

Comment: Please, use `std::bind` if you can. `other->*(this->method)()` should be `(other->*this->method)()` IIRC.

Comment: Already considered a solution involving [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) / [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)? At least a simple `typedef` for the member function type would help IMHO.

Comment: as i said I'm new to this and i havent even heard of std::bind or std::function, but they look interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c++
*(this->operation)(other->*(this->method)(), this->data);
^                         ^
```

Because of operator precedence, the *call operator* `()` is invoked before the function pointer is dereferenced. It will only be dereferenced *after* the call operator is invoked.

Change it to this:

```c++
(*this->operation)((other->*(this->method))(), this->data);
 ^                         ^
```

Notice that I also put another pair of parenthesis around `other->*(this->method)()`. This is needed because `(this->method)()` would have been evaluated before `other->*`.

---

Also, as @dyp says, you leave out most of the `this` qualifiers, making the result:

```c++
operation((other->*method)(), data);
```

Comment: `(*this->operation)` can also be just `this->operation`. Indirection is not required for a pointer-to-function. Not sure what's more readable (it's ugly anyway). Oh, and `this` can be left out, of course: `operation( (other->*method)(), data );`

Comment: @dyp  Update: Okay, I'll change that.

Comment: @dyp The syntax really got me. :)

Comment: OK, that's correct now :) I hope this shows nicely that the syntax should be avoided at all costs..

Comment: thanks a million, i got to get better at operator precedence, its way to confusing for me. also, thanks dyp, it really makes the whole thing more understandable

Comment: @user25470 No problem. Glad we could help! :)